# grammar 제도인 것으로 vs 제도로

Tags: grammar

I am reading an article comparing university system of Vietnam and Korea. Please look at the picture and yellow sentence below for more context.

I am confused about 은/ㄴ 것 grammar in the yellow sentence. Can I omit it and make it as simple as #2? Thanks.

> 1. 이는 베트남과 같은 **제도인 것으로** 보인다.
> 2. 이는 베트남과 같은 **제도로** 보인다.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here, they both mean more or less the same.  Literally,

> 이는 [베트남과 같은 제도인 것]으로 보인다. = This seems as if [it is the same system as in Vietnam].
>
> 이는 [베트남과 같은 제도]로 보인다. = This seems as [the same system as in Vietnam].

In other situations, only one of them may be appropriate.  For example,

> 정부는 [베트남과 같은 제도]를 목표로 했다. = The government aimed for [a system like Vietnam].
>
> (X) 정부는 [베트남과 같은 제도인 것]을 목표로 했다. = ???

- On the other hand, you *could* say "정부는 (X가) 베트남과 같은 제도가 되는 것을 목표로 했다." (The government's objective was to make X the same system as in Vietnam.)

Another example:

> 정부는 [(이것이) 베트남과 같은 제도인 것]을 적극 부인했다. = The government strongly denied that [(it) was the same system as in Vietnam].
>
> (X) 정부는 [베트남과 같은 제도]를 적극 부인했다. = ???